# Not able to view images in w3m

Tags: terminator, framebuffer, w3m

I was playing around with w3m (command-line browser), and found that it was not able to display images when run from `Terminator` or `gnome-terminal`. But, when run from `xterm`, it is able to display images.

I have both w3m and w3m-img packages installed.

After searching around a bit, I found some references about enabling frame buffer and stuff and couldn't quite understand all the terminology.

What should I do to make terminator run w3m properly with image preview support?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, `w3m` shows no images in either terminal. What website were you trying with?

Comment: What's the value of the DISPLAY environment variable (`echo $DISPLAY`)? You may need to add `export DISPLAY=:0.0` to your `.bashrc` or check `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` The `DISPLAY` variable lets image display programs find your display.

Comment: Same problem in 2017, no solution in 2017 ... :|

Comment: use xterm as your terminal emulator.